# Mechanics Deriving Kepler's Law

Tags: integration

Knowing that the acceleration of any body towards the centre of a star due to the force of gravity is proprtional to $$x^{-2} $$, where x is the distance of the body form the centre of the star, i.e. $$ x''= \frac k {x^2} $$, where k is a positive constant.
Knowing orbital speed is constant V at distance R from the centre of the star, how do you derive Kepler's 3rd law where $$k = {4\pi R^3\over T^2} $$

Comment: Should the $\pi$ be squared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more mathematical solution,

Let $\vec x $ be the two dimensional position vector from mass $M$ to (the center of) the satellite of mass $m$. Then,

$$\vec F=-m\frac{k}{r^2} \frac{\vec{x}}{||\vec x||}=-m\frac{k}{r^3} \vec x$$

(Negative sign because the force is inwards, towards the object of mass $M$)

At the same time $\vec F=m \frac{d^2}{dt^2}(\vec x)$ hence,

$$m \frac{d^2}{dt^2} \vec x=-m\frac{k}{r^3} \vec x$$

Now if we just look at one coordinate of the vector $x$, solving the second order ode:

$$x''=-\frac{k}{r^3}x$$

Gives real solutions of the form,

$$x=A\sin(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{r^3}}+\theta_1)$$

Or,

$$x=B\cos(t\sqrt{\frac{k}{r^3}}+\theta_2)$$

Notice that these solutions have period of $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{r^3}}}$ so,

$$T=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{r^3}}}$$

$$T^2=\frac{4 \pi^2 r^3}{k}$$

Hence,

$$k=\frac{4\pi^2r^3}{T^2}$$

---

Keplers law describes a body of mass $m$ in orbit with radius $r$ around a body of mass $M$, indeed we have,

$$F=ma=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

This is the force that keeps the body in orbit, that is it is what provides the centripetal  force of $m\frac{v^2}{r}$. Where $v$ is the velocity the body is traveling at.

Hence,

$$F=m\frac{v^2}{r}=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

This gives,

$$v^2=\frac{GM}{r}$$

But at the same time $v=\frac{2\pi r}{T}$ so,

$$\frac{4\pi^2 r^2}{T^2}=\frac{GM}{r}$$

Giving,

$$k=GM=\frac{4\pi^2 r^3}{T^2}$$

Comment: Wait do you know the way that you can do this through a mathematical way. By this I mean that you do not know F =GMM/r^2 but through integrating x^-2

Comment: I understand the physics way, but I have a maths question that requires me to do this, in a topic called 'Mechanics'

Comment: One second let me add that. Btw if $x''=0$ not what you said. It is true the acceleration vector is not zero but the distance from the satellite remains constant.

Comment: Please see the edit @D.Ronald

Comment: Also in my previous comment I mean that we have $x''=0$

Comment: I think the confusion your are having is that $a=||\vec x''||$ , we do not have $a=||\vec x||''$.